# Put SUM in attribute using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My Question is simple:

I have a `Lot` table with columns: `(id, product_id, quantity)`

I want to create one scope that group all registers by product_id and calculates `sum` 
of quantity column and return results on Array of Lot Objects.

I need this:

```
lots = Lot.sum_lots
lots.each do |lot|
  puts lot.product.name + " : " + lot.quantity.to_s
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Lot.sum(:quantity, :group => :product_id) # will return a hash: {1 => 22, 2 => 11}
```

The result is a hash with `product_id` as key and sum of `quantity` as value.

Comment: I think that should be `Lot.sum('quantity', :group => :product_id)`